# why is $u(x,y)$ derivable only between two specific curves?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, continuity

I've solved a PDE and got the resulting function:
$$u(x,y) = 2f(y-x) -f(y-2x) +\int_{y-2x}^{y-x} g(s)ds$$
The question then required me to specify the continuity of the function and when does it has a derivative given: $$g(y) = \begin{cases} 0 & y>2 \\ 1 &y \leq 2 \end{cases}$$ $$f(y) = y$$
I know that $f(y)$ is nice so the problem stems from $g(y)$, continuity wise $g$ is not continuous at $y=2$ but the integral smooths it out so $u$ is continuous across the entire curve. What I don't understand is why $u$ is only derivable within $y-x=2, y-2x=2$ - where does that come from? what's the "general algorithm" for answering similar questions?

 Edit: The PDE of which $u(x,y)$ is a solution is the following:
$$u_{xx} + 3u_{xy} + 2u_{yy} = 0 ; \quad x>0,  y\in \mathbb{R}\\u(0,y) = f(y); \quad y \in \mathbb{R} \\u_x(0,y) = g(y); \quad y \in \mathbb{R} $$

Comment: You claim that a certain PDE has a strange solution and you ask us to help you understand it. But you haven't even mentioned the PDE and how you found your solution.

Comment: my bad - added the PDE, solved it via classifying as a hyperbolic equation and changing variables accordingly. The solution is correct to the best of my knowledge since the problem is with a final solution and the answers match.